# (Codeigniter-jquery ui) Autocomplete not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-ui

My intension is to search users. But the autocomplete is not working for me. I would like some help on this.

Here are my codes,

**HTML**

```
<input id="user-input" type="text" name="users" placeholder="Search User" autocomplete="on">
```

**Model**

```
function get_user($user) {

    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->like('name', $user);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    // echo $query; die;

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
        }

        echo json_encode($row_set); 
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
public function user_search() {

    $this->load->model('users_model');

    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
        $user = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->users_model->get_user($user);
    }

}
```

**Js**

```
$(function(){
  $("#user-input").autocomplete({
    source: "site/user_search",
    minLength: 1
  });
});
```

I am using the jquery ui version 1.12

Comment: What error are you getting? If no error, can you check in the console what controller is being accessed when you start typing in?

Comment: no controller is being accessed. so i guess it could be the jquery-ui compatibility issue. also, data is not passing through the model to the controller

Comment: When I said controller... I was referring to the source you are accessing. When you start typing in, it sends request to source: "site/user_search". What is the full URL it is accessing. Also, what is the outcome of that AJAX request?

Comment: did you use firebug to check the ajax JSON response. if you are getting JSON response can you post it for further analysis. I also implemented jquery ui autocomplete in one of my CI projects and its code look similar as yours.

Comment: @Rahi the complete url is http://localhost:8888/JB-Revamped/index.php/site/index.

Comment: @GeordyJames thanks for suggesting firebug. i am not getting any json response.

Comment: Are you sure that `source: "site/user_search"` is getting data? Because if it is, you just have to care about the JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this work fine for me and for the sake of simplicity i removed the model.

In your view

```
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script>
     $(function(){
      $("#user-input").autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url('site/user_search'); ?>",
        minLength: 1
      });
    });
    </script> 
 <input id="user-input" type="text" name="users" placeholder="Search User" autocomplete="on">
```

In your Site Controller

```
    function user_search()
    {

        $user = $_GET['term'];

        $query = $this
                      ->db
                      ->select('name')
                      ->like('name',$user)
                      ->get('users');

         if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
                $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
            }

            echo json_encode($row_set); 
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Set label and value in json response key
 function user_search()
    {

        $user = $_GET['term'];

        $query = $this
                      ->db
                      ->select('name')
                      ->like('name',$user)
                      ->get('users');

         if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
                $new_row['label']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
                $new_row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
                $row_set[] = $new_row; //build an array
            }

            echo json_encode($row_set); 
 }
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.